# Looping JSON in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

I know this has been asked before but I am unable to get this working. Any help greatly appreciated.

This the contents of the var `obj`:

```
{
    "1": {
        "key1": "val",
        "key2": "val2"
    },
    "91": {
        "key1": "val",
        "key2": "val2"
    }
}
```

I am looping like this..

```
$.post("path/to/script.php", {
    'param': $('#param').val()
}, function (r) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(r);
    $.each(obj, function (k, v) {
        //doing some stuff with v.key1,v.key2 etc
    });
});
```

And getting a classically helpful JS error somewhere in jQuery

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

Comment: Try to add `console.log( typeof r )` inside the callback and see what it says ?

Comment: Yeah well spotted both r and obj are strings. Should have got that really. Why is it not parsing properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is nested, so you have to nest `each`.

```
var obj = {
    "1": {
        "key1": "val",
        "key2": "val2"
    },
    "91": {
        "key1": "val",
        "key2": "val2"
    }
};
```

If you are getting JSON as string, you need to parse the string into JSON.

```js
var r = '{"1": {"key1": "val","key2": "val2"},"91": {"key1": "val","key2": "val2"}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(r);
$.each(obj, function(k, v) {
  $.each(v, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L09bjjtc/1/

If you are getting the response as JSON, you can use the `dataType` option  of post method:

```
$.post( "test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" }, function( data ) {
    // data is JSON object
    // Data processing here
}, "json");
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but same issue. Have figured out that both r and the parsed variable obj are both ending up as strings

Comment: @MikeMiller Added `json` as `dataType`